# Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow

Tags: sql-server-2012, dateadd

I have cross applied a table valued function in a DML statement that returns two columns one of which is RiskValue (which is an integer denoting Scan Period)
Now when I print the value RiskValue along with dateadd function like this (y is function alias and am is another table)

```
select cast(y.RiskValue as int),dateadd(m,cast(y.RiskValue as int),@RunningDate)
from .....
```

it gives me proper values as

```
6    |    'Some Date'
```

but when I use it in a where clause as

```
where am.DateOpen >= dateadd(m,cast(y.RiskValue as int),@RunningDate)
```

I get the Error :

> Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow

Note that passing hard coded values as

```
where am.DateOpen >= dateadd(m,6,@RunningDate)
```

works fine. (Obviously it will)

Any suggestions what might be wrong?

Comment: What are the values of `@RunningDate` and `RiskValue`? The `date` type overflows after adding something that pushes it beyond the max of `9999-12-31` so your riskvalue has to be over 95000 or so if the runningdate is in 2015. Can it be? Also, what type does RunningValue have?

Comment: Sry for the delayed response. @RunningDate value ranges from 2015-05-10 to 2015-05-16. RiskValue is 6, Runnning Value has DateTime type

Comment: I can't recreate this error given those values, and it shouldn't be possible for it to happen. Are you absolutely sure that there isn't a large value in the RiskValue column?

Comment: that I am. I've printed the values using Select without the where clause, it works. The moment I introduce where clause, it doesn't. The only value RiskValue can contain for timebeing is 6

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. If the select works, then the where should too.

Comment: RiskValue is 6 *for that row*, but you have to understand that SQL Server may not optimize the statement in the same order you wrote it. It can often error out trying to perform calculations on values that should have been excluded by a filter, but the calculations were attempted *first*. See [this Connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) and [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/64493/1186). You can try `DATEADD(MONTH, CASE WHEN y.RiskValue < 20000 THEN y.RiskValue END, @RunningDate)`.

Comment: Also please see [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/93425/1186) and [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx).

Comment: That solves it. Thnx a lot Sir. You should have put it in answer so that I could have marked it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting Aaron Bertrand's comment as answer so that people reaching this question will find it helpful :

RiskValue is 6 for that row, but you have to understand that SQL Server may not optimize the statement in the same order you wrote it. It can often error out trying to perform calculations on values that should have been excluded by a filter, but the calculations were attempted first. We can try

```
DATEADD(MONTH, CASE WHEN y.RiskValue < 20000 THEN y.RiskValue END, @RunningDate)
```

Also read [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64489/cte-error-nvarchar-to-numeric/64493#64493) and [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93423/order-in-where-clause-matter-for-sargability/93425#93425) for better understanding